# C++ if statements in windows forms

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clr

I'm trying to make a program which tells you your zodiac sign.I have 2 text boxes for day and month , a button , and a richtextbox for output. I cannot get the if statements to work, the richtextbox shows the same thing for every input . For example it says Capricorn even if the day is 5 and the month 7. So, how can I make the if statements to work? 
I'm new to  C++ Windows forms, and visual studio, and I know it's a useless program, I just want to know how these things work.
here is my code inside the button:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    String ^ input = textBox2->Text;
    String^inputday = textBox1->Text;
    int luna; int day;
    luna = Convert::ToInt32(input);
    day = Convert::ToInt32(inputday);
    {if (luna == 1 && day < 20)

    {
        richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Capricorn ";
    }
    else { richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Aquarius"; }}


    {   if (luna == 2 && day < 19) { richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Aquarius"; }
    else { richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Pisces"; }}


    if (luna == 3 && day < 21) { richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Pisces"; }
    else { richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Aries"; }

    if (luna == 4 && day < 21) { richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Aries"; }
    else {
        richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Taurus";
    }
    if (luna == 5 && day < 22) { richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Taurus"; }
    else {
        richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Gemeni";
    }

    if (luna == 6 && day < 22) {
        richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Gemeni";
    }
    else { richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Cancer"; }

    if (luna == 7 && day < 22) {
        richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Cancer";
    }
    else {
        richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Leo";
    }

    if (luna == 8 && day < 23) {
        richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Leo";
    }
    else {
        richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Virgo";
    }

    if (luna == 9 && day < 23) {
        richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Virgo";
    }
    else {
        richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Libra";
    }

    if (luna == 10 && day < 23) {
        richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Libra";
    }
    else { richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Scorpio"; }

    if (luna == 11 && day < 22) {
        richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Scorpio";
    }
    else {
        richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Sagittarius";
    }
    if (luna == 12 && day < 22) {
        richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Sagittarius";
    }
    else {
        richTextBox1->Text = "Your sign is Capricorn";
    }
```

Comment: What did you observe when you stepped through your code line by line with the debugger? May be you need an `if() else if()` cascade instead of separate `if() else` pairs.

Comment: Not much to do with windows forms BTW.

Comment: Thank you , I think this should solve this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a problem in C++, it is a problem in the logic of `if` statements

it should be like this:

```
if (luna == 1)
    if (day < 20)
       //assign value
    else
        //assign value
else if (luna == 2)
    if (day < 19)
        //assign value
    else
        //assign value
else if (luna == 3) //and so on.....
```

Comment: I tried  something like this , but I did not connected the statements with an else if . I thought that the program will somehow get to the  next if statement.Thank you.

Comment: Mark it as answer if it is